# how do I create a Qt project option for linux only

Tags: qt

I know I can insert this to .pro file

```
win32 {
    LIBS += libbreakpad_client.lib
}
```

so that the option is only used when building under windows.

How do I do same for linux? I tried both

```
linux-g++ {
    LIBS += libbreakpad_client.a
}

linux {
    LIBS += libbreakpad_client.a
}
```

but it works only in qt5-qmake on qt4 it doesn't work at all...

Comment: According to the [Qt 4](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-advanced-usage.html#platform-scope-values) documentation you should be able to specify the scope based on the mkspec.

Comment: @Linville Did you manage to get that working? I read http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-advanced-usage.html#platform-scope-values, but neither setting `QMAKESPEC` as environment variable nor through `qmake -set` made the mkspec visible as `message($$QMAKESPEC)` in the `.pro` file ... (on Qt 4.8.1)

Comment: @Andreas, strange, just tested it on a Qt 4.8.6 snapshot and it doesn't work either. It looks like a documentation bug and the feature of scoping based on the mkspec is _not_ actually supported in Qt 4 (certainly not optimal, one could test against the environment variable $$(QMAKESPEC) but not everyone sets that). [Possibly related old bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-22700).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `unix`:

```
unix {
    message("Creating Makefile for UNIX ...")
    LIBS += libbreakpad_client.a
}
```